# How do I link a mobile website to my pc version Web site

Tags: html, css, mobile, web, filezilla

I have built a web page for a friend and it looks great on a pc, but when viewed on a device things overlap and look horrible. I built a simpler more responsive version for mobile. How do I code to make the mobile version come up when the site is accessed from a mobile device? I'm using html and css in my page, and filezilla as ftp client. Thanks for any help, I've researched this online but have found mixed answers all over, and never a direct answer. Maybe I'm not asking the question correctly?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question. **Note**, questions seeking help ("**why isn't, or how to make, this code working?**") must include the _**shortest code necessary**_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You should use the media query to define which css to use. For example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 800px)" href="mobile.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 1800px)" href="computer.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to make automatic redirection from your desktop site to your mobile site if it is visited from mobile device, the simplest way is to do it with Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (screen.width <= 768) {
document.location = "YOUR-MOBILE-SITE.com";
}
</script>
```

It works by check the browser page width, and if it is lower than 768px (usually mobile users width are less than it), it will redirect to your mobile site.

Alternatively, instead of doing such redirection, if you only change the CSS on your site (no radical html change), you could use coditional stylesheet instead of redirecting, so it will load your mobile optimized css file on mobile site :

```
<!-- Desktop CSS File -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="screen.css" media="screen"/> 
<!-- Mobile CSS File -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="handheld.css" media="handheld"/>
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help! Running smooth. It's a really simple site for a friend, but check it out @ cobrasvg.com. Thanks again.